# Recursion Depth error and stackover flow which happen in python

Tags: python, recursion, minimax

I recently created a tic tac toe game with the min-max function. However, I keep getting an error for stack overflow and recursion depth. How would you optimize this such as that it does not happen. I created the Tic Tac Toe game initially. Then I included the min-max algorithm.  If there anyway to make the code faster or optimize the function. This would really help thanks

```js
board = ["."] * 9
wining_comb = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,4,6],[0,4,8]]
game = True
key = {
  "x": 1,
  "O":-1,
}

def new_board():
    print (board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print (board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print (board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])

new_board()
def wining(comb):
    global game 
    for l in range(len(wining_comb)):
        a = wining_comb[l][0]
        f = wining_comb[l][1]
        v = wining_comb[l][2]
        if comb[a] == comb[f] == comb[v] == "O" or "x" == comb[a] == comb[f] == comb[v]:
            game = False 
            return a
            break
        else:
            game = True 
            break
            
def minmax(board,depth, ismax):
    if wining(board) != None:
        score = key[wining(board)]
        return score
    else:
        if ismax == True:
            bestscore = float('-inf')
            for k in range(len(board)):
                if board[k] == ".":
                    board[k] == "x"
                    score = minmax(board,depth+1,False)
                    board[k] == '.'
                    bestscore = max(bestscore, score)
            return bestscore 
        else:
            bestscore = float('inf')
            for k in range(len(board)):
                if board[k] == ".":
                    board[k] == "O"
                    score = minmax(board,depth+1,True)
                    board[k] == '.'
                    bestscore = min(bestscore,score)
            return bestscore
                    
                    

def player1() :
    bestscore = float('inf')
    bestmove = 0
    for k in range(len(board)):
        if board[k] == ".":
            board[k] == "x"
            score = minmax(board,0, False)
            board[k] == "."
            if score > bestscore:
                bestscore = score
                bestmove = k
    board[bestmove] = "x"
    new_board()
            
    
def player2():
    number = int(input("Please enter your poistion?") )
    board[number - 1 ] = "O"
    new_board()
    wining(board)



    
    
            


while game==True:
    player1()
    player2()
```

Comment: You get an infinite recursion error because your `minmax` function doesn't modify the game state; you probably typo'ed `==` for `=`. For example `board[k] == "x"` etc. These statements have no effect.

Comment: also notice: your `wining` function will always only run 1 iteration of the `for` loop (both `if` and `else` break...)

Comment: Also maybe check the correct English spelling of *winning.*